# What cards, if any, should I use for unimportant battles?

Tags: endless-space

When the outcome of a fight is pre-ordained, or it's otherwise unimportant, I'd like to skip choosing battle cards.  Are there a set of decent cards to which I should default?  Or will the AI learn that I favor certain cards, and start to pick countering cards?  If so, am I better off leaving them blank or just picking random cards?

Comment: I'm a fan of 'Nano-Repair Systems', heals your ships and is not countered by many cards. I believe that it still heals you even if the opponent is defeated/retreats early.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use Barrier, so that any damage is absorbed by the barrier and not by my ships. Ending with Nano-Repair Systems can heal any damage that snuck through.

Using Nano-Repair Systems the whole time would not be unreasonable, but it does reduce your weapons' damage.